# pip install throws MissingSectionHeaderError

Tags: python, macos, pip, easy-install

Pip version: 9.0.1

Python version: 2.7.13

Operating system: Mac OS

`MissingSectionHeaderError` is being thrown when I pip install anything. I was specifically trying to run `sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv`.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried to uninstall python3 and reinstall python3 (can't uninstall python2)

I've tried to re-download pip directly (from here: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/)

This is the error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 247, in move_wheel_files
    prefix=prefix,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/locations.py", line 141, in distutils_scheme
    d.parse_config_files()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 390, in parse_config_files
    parser.read(filename)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 512, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: setup.cfg, line: 7
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
```

I've tried `sudo find / | grep setup.cfg` to find the `setup.cfg` files, and compared them with a system that was working and they are the same.

I tried cd'ing into `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip` and doing `python3 __main__.py install --upgrade virtualenv` and it says it installed and the error was not thrown. However, I don't know where it has been installed (this should be possible with pip, because doesn't pip run this script?)

Very stumped as to what is going on. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Are you trying to install a package for python2 or python3?

Comment: I tried for both and I'm getting the error for both. I initially tried for Python 2 but either is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: running `pip install...` failed with `configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.`

In my case running `pip install -U pip` solved the error and I was able to install packages.